роутинг и передача данных в next js между страницами
мы используем next js у нас есть две страницы, одна основная main и другая (назовем её например shop)
также есть layout
Но кажется было бы логично, что есть layout
и он оборачивает main and shop
но у нас не так, чтобы перейти на shop нужно нажать на ссылку в хедере, такого типа
<Link href="/shop">

тогда url меняется и мы попадаем на страницу "магазин"
получается это две отдельные страницы и пропсы я туда никак не передам,
я в layout по ручке получаю данные и мне нужно чтобы эти данные попали в обе страницы,
но учитывая, что shop это отдельная страница, я не знаю как сделать так чтобы данные попали на обе страницы и чтобы не делать два отдельных запроса на каждой странице, блин у меня всегда было какое-то непонимание как это работает, может кто подскажет?

как вариант использовать state-manager, но тогда нужно будет использовать клиентские компоненты (use client) или посмотреть в сторону библиотеки SWR
